# Laptop power supply wattage differences on identical specs?

Tags: power-supply, laptop

I was comparing the Macbook Pro 15" 2015 (highest end) with the Lenovo W541 with similar specs (same CPU, very similar GPU, etc.) and the MBP is supplied with a 85W power adapter, while the Lenovo has a 170W adapter. Why is it that Lenovo has been shipping ever higher wattage power supplies with their laptops, while Apple is only sending a paltry 85W? Which, BTW, doesn't seem like it would be enough to fully power the CPU and GPU delivered under full load. The processor alone has a TDP of 47W, so it doesn't seem like there's enough power being delivered here.

Comment: The adapter is used mainly for battery charging. Have you compared the batteries?

Comment: It could also be simple economy--stock one size that supports many models and buy in larger quantity.

Comment: Well, according to this review of the W541, they recorded peak consumption of 121 Watts on the Thinkpad, which exceeds Apple's 85 Watts. So I'm guessing that you can't run full tilt on an empty battery on a Macbook Pro, and your cease charging the battery if you do run flat out.

Comment: http://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-ThinkPad-W541-Workstation-Review.137450.0.html